# PHP logical operators in IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, logical-operators

I have this code:

```
if ( ($oldTime < (time() - self::wait)) ) {
  if ($this->setTime())
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Can i replace it with:

```
if ( ($oTime < (time() - self::wait)) && $this->setTime() ) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

I need it to check if `$this->setTime()` returns true ONLY if `$oTime < (time() - self::wait)` is true.

Comment: Yes you can, this is the same.

Comment: *Offtopic* Dude, we've got the same avatar... Respect my authority! :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return ($oTime < (time() - self::wait)) && $this->setTime()
```

Comment: So i can to the replacement right? and if `$oTime < (time() - self::wait)` is false, `$this->setTime()` will not be executed?

Comment: Yes, if I am understanding you correctly.  && is a short-circuiting operator, so if the first condition is false, the second condition will not execute.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use this

```
if ( ($oTime < (time() - self::wait)) && $this->setTime() ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if first condition in the if statement with && ( not || ) fails, it will go to the else branch automatically without verifying the second condition